# Markers in Matplotlib graph don't have outlines

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a 3D scatter plot in Matplotlib using

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
...
ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker = '0', color=color1)
```

and my markers on the graph don't have the usual black outline.  When I remove my color argument the outline comes back.  Does anyone know how to get the default black outline on the markers but still have my custom color defined?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the argument `edgecolor=` it may be off by default if the color of the marker was specified.

Comment: Thanks very much, I was trying to use `markeredgecolor=` from a previous question I found.